Loop API values in R
I need to make looping API calls where a variable changes each time.  For example, I have approximately 1300 values so I'd need 1300 calls since the API will only provide the information for a single value per call.  I've tried various changes without any success.  If I specify a single value, I can get the information.
Here is the portion of the script causing the issue:
#get the 1st page (seed)
    call_prospeststatus <- paste0(base,endpoint,"/","21894","/prospectstatus",sep="")
    get_prospectstatus <- GET(call_prospeststatus, add_headers("Bb-Api-Subscription-Key" = subscription_key, "Authorization" = paste0("Bearer ",access_token,sep="")))
    get_prospectstatus_text <- content(get_prospectstatus, "text")
    get_prospectstatus_json <- fromJSON(get_prospectstatus_text, flatten = TRUE)
    get_prospectstatus_df <- as.data.frame(get_prospectstatus_json)


#get the rest
for(i in 1:length(Prospect_IDs_DF)){
    call_prospeststatus <- paste0(base,endpoint,"/",Prospect_IDs_DF[[i]],"/prospectstatus",sep = "")
    get_prospectstatus <- GET(call_prospeststatus, add_headers("Bb-Api-Subscription-Key" = subscription_key, "Authorization" = paste0("Bearer ",access_token,sep = "")))
    get_prospectstatus_text <- content(get_prospectstatus, "text")
    get_prospectstatus_json <- fromJSON(get_prospectstatus_text, flatten = TRUE)
    if (get_prospectstatus$status_code == '200'){
    get_prospectstatus_df_2 <- as.data.frame(get_prospectstatus_json)
  } else {
    get_prospectstatus_df_2 <- get_prospectstatus_df[FALSE,]
  }
   get_prospectstatus_df <- bind_rows(get_prospectstatus_df, get_prospectstatus_df_2)
}


The 'seed' portion works but the 'rest' gives this error.
Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE.
I've noticed that the call values in the environment pane show concatenated URL calls instead of a single call.  I'm a relatively unskilled R user so any help would be greatly appreciated.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Define all variables so we can see what's in them. What is the value of call_prospeststatus when you call GET? It sounds like it's a vector of multiple values and it needs to have just one value.

Is Prospect_IDs_DF a  data.frame? If yes, you are cycling through its columns and Prospect_IDs_DF[[i]] is a vector of i-th column values.

It looks like your loop will overwrite the prior loop's value.  Read about creating a list or vector to store the data.

@MrFlick you are correct.  The vector has multiple values but needs to have just one.

@MrFlick I want to take the first value from 'Prospect_IDs_DF', use it in my API call, get the corresponding information from the API, save it, and then repeat for the next value in 'Prospect_IDs_DF'.  Currently I get a long string of all the calls concatenated together and, as expected, the API source doesn't know what to do with it so gives me an error.  I hope my explanation make sense.  I know an example would be helpful and perhaps I will try to make one.
